# Service worker requires double refresh

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm having problems making my service worker do what I want, and here is what it is:

- provide offline verison of website
- refresh content whenever it is updated

What it currently does is alright except that whenever I change the content of my page I need to refresh it twice before I see the changes. What can I do to keep the offline fallback but get fresh content with only one refresh of the page?

```
const version = "0.6.25";
const cacheName = `cache-${version}`;
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
            return cache.addAll([
                `/`,
                `/index.html`,
                '/1.jpg',
            ])
                .then(() => self.skipWaiting());
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(async function() {
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
        const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);
        const networkResponsePromise = fetch(event.request);

        event.waitUntil(async function() {
            const networkResponse = await networkResponsePromise;
            await cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
        }());

        // Returned the cached response if we have one, otherwise return the network response.
        return cachedResponse || networkResponsePromise;
    }());
});
```

I tried switching `cachedResponse` with `networkResponsePromise` in the last line but then I lose the offline fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achived it by changing `const networkResponsePromise` to this:

```
const networkResponsePromise = fetch(event.request).then().catch(()=> {
        return cachedResponse;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this myself and found the following solution to work very well:

- Implement a cache-first approach: load assets into cache on installation. On fetch, try load from cache, and fetch from network otherwise.
- Make the server overwrite the cache name in the Service Worker script, using a hash of the asset contents. This will automatically make the browser install the new app whenever your assets change.
- Detect when the browser installs a new SW. In my cases I do an auto-reload if it's less than 3s since the page loaded. Otherwise I show a notification.

I wrote it up in more detail here: https://almarklein.org/pwa.html